# What is proc and sysfs entries

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, linux-device-driver

I'd like to learn about `proc and sysfs entries`.

So far, what I have understood is that, proc entries are the values which is set to proc file system. I'm not sure whether I'm correct. Could anyone explain it in detail about its real need and where it is used? Please provide me links to know it better. Any kind of guidance is accepted.

Comment: Did you try google "linux proc filesystem"?

Comment: @Dhasneem - A nice article I found: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The /proc filesystem is a special, software-created filesystem that is used by the kernel to export information to the world. Each file under /proc is tied to a kernel function that generates the file's "contents" on the fly when the file is read. We have already seen some of these files in action; /proc/modules, for example, always returns a list of the currently loaded modules.

/proc is heavily used in the Linux system. Many utilities on a modern Linux distribution, such as ps, top, and uptime, get their information from /proc. Some device drivers also export information via /proc, and yours can do so as well. The /proc filesystem is dynamic, so your module can add or remove entries at any time.

Fully featured /proc entries can be complicated beasts; among other things, they can be written to as well as read from. Most of the time, however, /proc entries are readonly files. This section concerns itself with the simple read-only case. Those who are interested in implementing something more complicated can look here for the basics; the kernel source may then be consulted for the full picture.

Before we continue, however, we should mention that adding files under /proc is discouraged. The /proc filesystem is seen by the kernel developers as a bit of an uncontrolled mess that has gone far beyond its original purpose (which was to provide information about the processes running in the system). The recommended way of making information available in new code is via sysfs. As suggested, working with sysfs requires an understanding of the Linux device model, however, and we do not

source - http://tjworld.net/books/ldd3/#UsingTheProcFilesystem

Answer (score -2):

u can look at the ldd3 for more detailes.
it is often used as a tool for debuging the device drivers.
i am a newbie.
good luck.